# Popen and stdin to automate input to .exe

Tags: python, stdin, popen

I have a simple windows executable that asks for user input and I'm trying to make a python script to automate the input. 
What I've done:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen([r'myprgm.exe'], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input=bytes(input("Test Input"), 'UTF-8'))
```

Now, normally when the program runs, it outputs to the command prompt "give me input:" then expects input from the user.

If I use Popen with the `stdin=PIPE` option, nothing is written to the command prompt at all - it just sits there blank.

Then, when I use communicate, "Test Input" ends up on the python console, and not to the process.

Is it possible to automate something like this? Or am I missing something fundamental here..

Comment: You have to give input before calling `communicate`

Answer (score 2):

You can give `input` to [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) function.

like

```
p1 = Popen(["mycmd"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
output = p1.communicate(input="my input")[0]
```

Comment: You need stdin=PIPE also.

Comment: Sorry copy paste mistake :)

Comment: OP uses Python 3 and where you must pass `bytes` as `input` value unless the text mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

> "Test Input" ends up on the python console

You see the output because [`input(prompt)` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) prints it. If you want to pass `Test Input` literally to the subprocess then drop `input()` call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('myprgm.exe', stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input=b"Test Input")
```

It is not guaranteed that `myprgm.exe` accepts utf-8 input on Windows (it might accept input encoded using Windows console OEM encoding such as `cp437` or Windows ANSI encoding such as `cp1252` instead) and therefore `bytes(unicode_string, 'utf-8')` input may be wrong. It should be ok to pass a bytestring with bytes in ascii range (created using `b''` bytes literal)).